# Extract just the depot path from perforce output

Tags: regex, perforce

Already tried a few of the "Extract up to a character" questions here, none work.
Using this in grep -o

example input:
//blah/blah/foo.txt#7 - edit change 12526 (text) by blah@blah

I want to get:
//blah/blah/foo.txt

Right now I am using the regex '/[^#]*/' but I get
//blah/blah/

Comment: What tool?  Perl?  Ruby?  Python?  grep?  You really need to provide more information

Comment: Sorry, this is just using on grep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`grep` does not use slashes to delimit the pattern, so the slashes are being matched literally.

Try:

```
echo '//blah/blah/foo.txt#7 - edit change 12526 (text)' | grep -o '/[^#]*'
```

Note that if the "text" has a slash in it, that part will also match and will therefore be printed by `grep -o`.  So I would go with something like this:

```
echo '//blah/blah/foo.txt#7 - edit change 12526 (text)' | sed 's/#.*//'
```

(Both of these assume there is no # in your file names, of course.)

Comment: That did it, thanks. The text after the # should NOT have a slash in it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut`.

`<whatever it takes to get your output> | cut -f1 -d"#"`

So, if you are grepping contents of a file or something like that.

`grep -o "whatever text" inputFile | cut -f1 -d"#"`

The `-d"#"` means use the "#" as a delimiter, `-f1` means the first field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `/^.*(?=#)/` It uses a (non-consuming) look-ahead

Answer (score 0):

It's helpful to use "tagged" mode when you are doing scripting like this, since tagged output is easier to parse and process. See "-ztag" in http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/cmdref/o.gopts.html#1040647 and also have a look at http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r10.2/manuals/p4script/index.html